# Save username and password after closing the app

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences

I became really confused and I couldn't find my answer in other questions . I have a simple page with three edit texts . The first one is the Username , the second one is the Password and the third one is re entering the Password . I used intent to show them in the second  Activity . Then I asked to write Username and Password to enter the third page,I don't want to see the first page any more  (After closing the app) and I want to have the entered Username and Password for future uses.

Well here is my code in the first class:

```
package com.example.Test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn1;
    EditText edit1;
    EditText edit2;
    EditText edit3;
    TextView txt1;
    TextView txt2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        edit3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit3);
        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if((edit2.getText().toString().equals(edit3.getText().toString()))&(!edit2.getText().toString().equals("")))
            if (edit1.getText().toString().equals(""))
                txt1.setText("username field is empty");
            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent
                        (MyActivity.this,MyActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("myString", edit1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("myString2", edit2.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        else txt1.setText("passwords aren't same");
    }
});
    }




}
```

And this one is my second class

```
package com.example.Test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyActivity2 extends Activity {
TextView txt2;
    TextView txt4;
    EditText us1;
    EditText pw1;
    Button button1;
    TextView txt5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("myString");
        String myString2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("myString2");
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        txt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt4);
        txt5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt5);
        txt2.setText(myString);
        txt4.setText(myString2);
        us1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.us1);
        pw1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pw1);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if((us1.getText().toString().equals(txt2.getText().toString())&(pw1.getText().toString().equals(txt4.getText().toString()))))
                    startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity2.this,MyActivity3.class));
                 else {
                    txt5.setText("Username or Password is incorrect");


                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I want to use something else instead of txt4 (a TextView that it should be equal with an EditText)  and have it saved.

If you just didnt understand what I need,please tell me to explain more.:D

Answer (score 0):

you should use SharedPreference. 
e.g.

to get the SharedPreference object (context isn't important, few contexts gives this same prefs)

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

to save something to SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("Username", "user");
editor.putString("Password", "pass");
editor.commit();
```

to get something from SharedPreferences

```
String name = settings.getString("Username", "null");
```

the second value is value if SharedPreference for this first one isn't set.

then in onCreate you can do this:

```
String name = settings.getString("Username", "null");
if (!name.equals("null")) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
}
```